# Hide exported PowerShell functions from the user

Tags: powershell, module, restrict

So the title makes it pretty much clear but I will ask more precise anyway.
So the question is whether is it possible to export helper functions from a module and make them only available to reuse in code, but restricted to the user so he cannot call them from the console?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you say available to reuse in code, are you referring to code in the module, a script external to the module, a separate module?

Comment: I need to use certain functions in separate modules, without making those functions available to the user console

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need to just specify what you are exporting like so (in psm file):

```
Export-ModuleMember  -Function Verb-Noun
```

That would export only this one function and in your psd file:

```
FunctionsToExport = 'Verb-Noun'
```

Comment: I have this right now, but this makes the functions available not only to separate module but the user can call them from the console as well

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you are saying, can you rephrase? For me it works as expected: `Get-Command -Module mymodule` returns only 1 command. Add examples? @SokIsKedu

Comment: Read the comment on the question itself, he needs the methods to be available to other modules but not available to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible the way you want to do it. How I would handle it is have a PS1 file in the helper module that contains all the hidden commands, but not load it as part of the helper module. Then in the modules that depend on it, simply dot source the PS1 helper file and it will import all the scripts for it to use.

Eg, in the module requiring the helper module:

```
. $PSScriptRoot\..\HelperModule\HelperModuleInternal.ps1
```

Obviously replace HelperModule and HelperModuleInternal with the name of the helper module and the hidden commands ps1 file respectively. Note if you make it a psm1 file this will just open the ISE.

I'm not sure but it might still try to export the hidden commands, if this is the case I read a neat trick on dealing with it. Call all your published commands the usual `Verb-Noun` syntax, and at the end put `Export-ModuleMember -Function "*-*"`. Then for your internal commands, use naming that does not conform to this, eg `Verb_Noun` or `VerbNoun`. Very tidy.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to achieve what you want, neither of them clean or intuitive though. I think the issue is caused by the auto-loading of any modules in the `$Env:PSModulePath` directories. Here's what worked for me, you can pick your poison.

**Option 1: Turn off module auto-loading**

- In the parent module manifest, add the name of the helper module as a nested module:
  `NestedModules = @('MyHelperModule')`
- In your profile, set `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference` to either `'None'` or `'ModuleQualified'`. This will prevent your helper module from auto-loading and therefore being exposed to the user. Unfortunately it will also prevent all other modules from auto-loading, which means you'll also have to add `Import-Module` statements to your profile to explicitly load the ones you want to be there at the start of each session, and manually import any additional ones as you go. Depending on how you work, this may be more trouble than it's worth.

**Option 2: Move the helper module**

- Move the helper module into a directory that's not in the `$Env:PSModulePath` list, e.g. C:\MyHiddenModules\MyHelperModule.
- In the parent module manifest, add the full path of the helper module as a nested module:
  `NestedModules = @('C:\MyHiddenModules\MyHelperModule\MyHelperModule.psm1')`

In both cases, you can use the FunctionsToExport array in the parent manifest to control which, if any, of the helper functions you want to expose to the user.

Details on the [$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7#psmoduleautoloadingpreference) preference variable.

Answer (score 0):

### Use case criteria:

- Function is stored in a powershell module or script file
- Load a function into memory
- You do not want to dot source the entire file because the script might have executable commands
- You don't want to manually parse the file because doing that is gross
- When you're done using your function you want it obliterated so the user doesn't have access to it
- You don't want to or can't load the entire module containing the desired function

### Limitations:

- Powershell logging will still show this was executed
- You know the exact file where the function stored

### How explained:

- Wrap your code into a try/finally block.
- In the `Try` block

  - use `Get-Function` to collect the desired function by name and pipe the results into `Invoke-Expression` to load it into memory. The loaded function will only be stored in the scope of the current powershell instance and will not be available to other powershell instances on the same computer.
  - then execute the commands you'd like
- In the `Finally` block

  - execute a command to remove the previously loaded function to prevent the user from accessing them
  - code contained in a finally block is executed before control is passed back to the user, even if the user presses <kbd>Control + C</kbd> at any point during your run

### How example:

```
Try {
    # load the 
    Get-Function -Path "$($ModulePath)\Library_GeneralPurpose.ps1" -Name Get-DeathStarPlans | Invoke-Expression

    # run the super secret function
    Get-DeathStarPlans -IncludeCriticalWeaknesses
    }
Finally {
    # remove function from memory to prevent rebel alliance from accessing the source code or running it them selves
    Remove-Item -Path Function:\Get-DeathStarPlans -Force
    }
```

### Get-Function

This function would need to already be loaded or you could cannibalize the specific commands.

```
function Get-Function {
    <# 
    .SYNOPSIS 
        Returns a named function from a .ps1 file without executing the file
    .DESCRIPTION
        This is useful where you have a blended file containing functions and executed instructions.

        If neither -Names nor -Regex are provided then all functions in the file are returned.
        Returned objects can be piped directly into Invoke-Expression which will place them into the current scope.

        Returns an array of objects with the following
            - .ToString()
            - .Name
            - .Parameters
            - .Body
            - .Extent
            - .IsFilter
            - .IsWorkFlow
            - .Parent

    .PARAMETER -Files
        Array of file paths or file objects;
        These files will be parsed

    .PARAMETER -Names 
        Array of Strings; Optional; Case Insensitive
        If provided then function objects of these names will be returned
        The name must exactly match the provided value

    .PARAMETER -Regex
        Regular Expression; Optional; Case Insensitive
        If provided then function objects with names that match will be returned

    .EXAMPLE
        Get all the functions names included in the file
            Get-Function -name TestA | Select-Object name

    .EXAMPLE
        Import a function into the current scope
            Get-Function -name TestA | Invoke-Expression

    .EXAMPLE
        Get a single function from this library file
            $Function = "$($ModulePath)\Library_GeneralPurpose.ps1" | Get-Function -Name Get-Function
            $Function.ToString()

    .EXAMPLE
        Load a function then remove it to prevent it from being usable by the user
            Try {
                # load the 
                "$($ModulePath)\Library_GeneralPurpose.ps1" | Get-Function -Name Get-DeathStarPlans | Invoke-Expression

                # run the super secret function
                Get-DeathStarPlans -IncludeCriticalWeaknesses
                }
            Finally {
                # remove function from memory to prevent rebel alliance from accessing the source code
                Remove-Item -Path Function:\Get-DeathStarPlans -Force
                } 
    #>
    param (
        [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [alias("File", "Paths")]
        $Files
        , 
        [alias("Name", "FunctionNames", "Functions")]
        $Names
        ,
        [alias("NameRegex")]
        $Regex
        ) # end function
    Process {
        foreach ( $File in $Files ) {
            # get the script
            $Script = $File | Get-Item | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname | Get-Command
            # parse out all the functions
            $AllFunctions = $Script.ScriptBlock.AST.FindAll({$args[0] -is [Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst]}, $false)

            # return all requested functions
            $AllFunctions | Where-Object { `
                ( $Names -and $Names -icontains $_.Name ) `
                -or ( $Regex -and $_.Name -imatch $Regex ) `
                -or (-not $Names -and -not $Regex) `
                } # end where-object
            } # next file
        } # end process
    } # end function Get-Function
```